# How to change a char to a string?

Tags: c++, string, dictionary, char

I have this function:

```
void map()
{
   map<char, string> change;  
   string usrstr = "A APPLE AND BANANA";

   change['A'] = "00011";
   change['B'] = "11001";
   change['C'] = "01110";
   change[' '] = "$$";

}
```

How would I go about changing all occurrences of 'A' in my string to "00011" and the same for B, C and space. All help is much appreciated

P.S The string wont always be the same

Comment: If the question is about C++, it should be tagged `c++` exclusively.

Comment: Er, use the `replace()` method

Comment: replace() only works when you want to replace a char with a char, i want to replace the char with a string.

Comment: [`string::replace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace), not `std::replace`.

Comment: ok maybe i should of said this for the start, the string isnt always going to be "A APPLE AND BANANA" so if i use string::replace it will only work for that one string. Sorry for not being clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can and should probably use `string::replace`. 
Even with your most recent comment.

But this might have been what you were trying to do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>
#include <map>
#include <string>


using namespace std;


int main()
{
    char temp;

    map<char, char*> change;

    string lol = "A APPLE AND BANANA";

    change['A'] = "00011";
    change['B'] = "11001";
    change['C'] = "01110";
    change[' '] = "$$";


    for (int i = 0; i < lol.length(); i++)
    {
        temp = lol[i];
        if (change[temp])
            cout << change[temp];
        else
            cout << lol[i];
    }

    cout << endl;

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what i wanted to do, Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

Not sure to understand: how about:

```
std::string str = "A APPLE AND BANANA";
std::replace(str.begin(), str.end(), "A", "00011" );
std::replace(str.begin(), str.end(), "B", "11001" );
...
```

Comment: `std::replace` replaces single elements. And `'00011'` is not even valid C++...